# Datatables with live click event function

Tags: jquery, datatables

What I am attempting to do is when the user clicks on the View All Content Pages it goes OUT of pagination view so I want it to remove the pagination links which it removes the pages but not the First Preview Next Last links, however when a user clicks on View Paginated Records then it adds the First Preview Next Last links.

http://jsfiddle.net/xtremer360/hrfYA/7/

Comment: So you want to hide the 'First Preview Next Last' buttons when pagination is disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show/hide the pagination controls according to what you are doing you just need to show/hide them:

```
$('.viewAll').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(-1);
    $(this).removeClass('viewAll').addClass('paginateRecords');
    $(this).find('strong').html('View Paginated Records');
    $('.pagination').hide();
});

$('.paginateRecords').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    oTable.fnLengthChange(10);
    $(this).removeClass('paginateRecords').addClass('viewAll');
    $(this).find('strong').html('View All Content Pages');    
    $('.pagination').show();    
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/hrfYA/9/

Comment: I've said it was and I'll said it again you are amazing.

Comment: There's only one last thing I have to do with my script that deals with the dataTables plugin and that's css related. Lets say you're on page 1 of 3. In that case the First and Last buttons should be disabled. I have a special style that gets applied to disabled buttons but they get canceled out because there's other styles applied to them and it doesn't show the disabled button style.